# Create Beans programatically using other Beans

Tags: spring

I use the Interface `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` to create Beans.

But i need the info from another Bean there. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you show the code, how do you create a bean with `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`?

Comment: I dont have the code yet. In the methode `public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {` i need to get some information from another bean.

Comment: At that moment bean does not yet exist. You can get just `BeanDefinition` but not bean.